# converting double into date

Tags: r, double

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTYoj.jpg)

I have trouble converting double data into a date. I want to convert a date by using as_date. However, when I apply this function, I am getting strange output. I think the problem lays the horizontal line under the numbers (see the image). Does someone know how I can delete this line or escape?

Comment: Please dont add links to outside websites and always post your code when seeking helpl.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

df$date <- ymd(df$date)

# [1] "1995-10-11" "1995-01-03"
```

Or use a combination of `strptime` and `as.Date`:

```
df$date <- as.Date(strptime(df$date, format = "%Y%m%d"))
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = c(19951011, 19950103)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```